# Azure DevOps disable 'delete branch' after merge permanent on release branch (Folder: release/*)

Tags: azure-devops, merge, permissions, branching-and-merging

I want to permanent disable 'delete Branch' on a specific branch after merging.

Is there a way to avoid this permanently. That all cases for deletion are not possible. Since this is a release branch and must remain after the merge. Unfortunately, it has already happened that the 'delete branch' hack was not removed and the release branch was therefore deleted.

[image: 1]

The marked checkbox should be permanent grey or not there. Is it possible to do this?

The marked checkbox should be permanent grey or not there. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a branch policy to the branch you want protected, it will no longer be eligible for deletion. However, merging into that branch will then require a pull request.

Comment: I 2nd OP's request. I wish this "Delete Branch after merge" checkbox didn't even exist. There is never a scenario in which we want a branch merged into main to be AUTO-deleted after a pull request is completed.

Comment: @BryanWilliams That's odd, because I can't imagine a scenario where I *want* to retain merged feature branches.